# Python sqlite3 executescript() error with multiple inserts

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm in the process of transferring my brain from PHP + MySQL to Python and at the moment I'm using sqlite as an intermediary to something else later because it's built in.

When I try to set up an initial database to work with, it throws an error on the `INSERT` statement that `INSERT`s multiple rows:

```
import sqlite3

query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
             "userID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
             "email" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
             "forename" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
             "surname" varchar(50) NOT NULL
           );
           INSERT INTO "users" ("userID", "email", "forename", "surname") 
           VALUES
             (1, 'user1@example.com', 'Test', 'User'),
             (2, 'user2@example.com', 'Test', 'User');"""

 db_conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
 try:
     db_conn.cursor().executescript(query)
     db_conn.commit()
 except:
     print "error with database"
     raise
 finally:
     db_conn.close()
```

When I run it, I get:

```
error with database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbTest.py", line 20, in <module>
    db_conn.cursor().executescript(query)
sqlite2.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

It took me quite a while to find exactly which "," it didn't like (I mean, really? SQL errors suck!). It is indeed the "," separating `INSERT` rows.

What stupid thing did I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your insert I would use [.executemany()](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) instead of execute script, if you can. Otherwise if you can't, your `INSERT` statement will need to be seperate for each `VALUES` set you wish to pass it.

```
query = """INSERT INTO "users" ("userID", "email", "forename", "surname") 
           VALUES
           (?, ?, ?, ?)
        """
user_list = ((1, 'user1@example.com', 'Test', 'User'), (2, 'user2@example.com', 'Test', 'User'))
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO myTable(data) values (?) ", user_list)
```

EDIT:
According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database), you can in fact have multiple value sets in a single `INSERT` statement, but the syntax is far from pretty.

Comment: ok, that's a bit of a pain - obviously not a problem once everything is set up, but I wanted to transport the database from a mysql dump to get it up and running

Comment: I found a post similar to yours, which is linked in the `EDIT` section of my post. It does appear to be possible to have a multi-row insert, but the syntax doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Ah, so it's a feature that's not actually supported by sqlite - according to that post it was added in version 3.7.11, which is why this page http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html says you can have them, which is why I used it! I must have an older version - I'm just using whatever I got in my Python install! I'd rather type the data in by hand than use `UNION SELECT` like that! Thank you